# Why does this curried method need to be wrapped by a function?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash

In the example below, I would expect that one could pass the curried function as a predicate to the `any` function. However, it only produces the correct result when the curried function is wrapped. Why does this behaviour occur?

```
var isGreaterThanOneCurried = _.curryRight(_.gt, 2)(1);
var isGreaterThanOneNoCurry = function(value) { return value > 1; };
var listOfOnes = [1, 1];    

// CORRECT! returns false
_.any(listOfOnes, function(value) { return isGreaterThanOneCurried(value); }); 

// INCORRECT! returns true
_.any(listOfOnes, isGreaterThanOneCurried); 

// CORRECT! returns false
_.any(listOfOnes, isGreaterThanOneNoCurry);
```

Comment: Well, the first thing that is different is that the second example passes more than one argument to `isGreaterThanOneCurried`. Maybe that messes with the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the documentation for [`_.some`](https://lodash.com/docs#some) (`_.any` is an alias for `_.some`):

> The predicate is bound to thisArg and invoked with three arguments:
>   (value, index|key, collection).

Though you have curried from the right, the function still accepts multiple arguments (even though curried functions, by definition, are not supposed to accept multiple arguments, lodash contradicts that definition here). Those multiple arguments are supplied from left-to-right, so what you end up with is an arguments list that looks like this:

```
[1, 0, [1, 1], 1]
```

The first three are supplied by `_.any`, and the final one is one you supplied after right-currying.

You can verify this pretty easily:

```
var _ = require('lodash')

var listOfOnes = [1, 1]

function logArgsify(fn) {
  return function() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(arguments)))
    return fn.apply(null, arguments)
  }
}

var gt = logArgsify(_.gt)

var isGreaterThanOneCurried = _.curryRight(gt, 2)(1)

_.any(listOfOnes, isGreaterThanOneCurried)
// Output: [1,0,[1,1],1]
```

- first argument is 1 (value)
- second argument is 0 (index)
- third argument is [1, 1] (collection)
- fourth argument: 1, supplied earlier
- [`_.gt`](https://lodash.com/docs#gt) only considers two arguments
- 1 > 0 is true

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Using `_.ary` forcing the curried method to one caused it to have the desired behaviour. The curry method accepting more than one argument threw me off.

Comment: @Pete Yeah, it's contrary to what I would expect from `curry` as well. Good thing there is `_.ary` :)